# SBT not finding resolvers added in another sbt file

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a SBT project, where I have added the resolvers in `build.sbt`. Now, instead of adding the resolvers in build.sbt file, I am trying to put in a new file, `resolvers.sbt`. 
But the SBT is unable to find the artifacts if I make the resolvers in separate file. However, I can see the message while starting up the SBT that, my resolvers.sbt is being considered.

If I add the resolvers to global file in `.sbt` directory, it is getting resolved.

sbt version : 1.2.6

Did anyone else faced the same issue ?

**build.sbt**

```
import sbt.Credentials

name := "sbt-sample"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.reactore" %% "reactore-infra" % "1.0.0.0-DEV-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

**resolvers.sbt**

```
credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "192.168.1.120", "yadu", "password")

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Reactore-snapshots" at "http://192.168.1.120:8182/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local"
)
```

**SBT Log**

```
sbt:sbt-sample> reload
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/administrator/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading settings for project sbt-sample-build from resolvers.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/administrator/source/poc/sbt-sample/project
[info] Loading settings for project sbt-sample from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to sbt-sample (in build file:/home/administrator/source/poc/sbt-sample/)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my own question here, hoping that it will be useful for someone else.

Found out the issue, I was keeping the resolvers.sbt inside project directory. I moved it to the project's home directory (where build.sbt is present), and now it is resolving.